# Convert categorical features with and without unique seperators using pd.get_dummies in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, data-manipulation

**Details about the goal**

I am trying to use pd.get_dummies in pandas to convert the categorical features to data frames with dummy/indicator variables for each of three different genres, demographics, and prices separately.

**Additional details**

Two have a separator one a "," and another a "| " and the third there is only one choice it has a comma but that is part of the price not a separator.

**Overall goal - beyond this fix**

After I am done I would like to run a scaling function returns a numpy array containing the features KNN model from scikit-learn to the data and calculate the nearest neighbors for each distances.

**import and load dataset**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

artist = pd.read_csv("artist.csv")

artist.head()
```

**This is the current dataframe**

I simplified as the real data frame is massive thousand of names, genres, prices points and demographics.

**Dataframe:**

```
id |            name              |       genre                              |     price         |     demo                 |      songs     |         bio      |
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 1 |           Ace Frehley         |    Classic Rock,Rock Music               |   Call For Fee    |  25-35,35-50,50 +        |
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 2 |           Air Supply         | Adult Contemporary, Pop Music            |   Call For Fee    |  35-50, 50 +             |
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 3 |           Bebe Rexha         |  Country Music, Hip Hop & Rap, Pop Music |   Call For Fee    |  Undefined               |
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 4 |           Blanco Brown       |           Hip Hop & Rap, R&B             |   Call For Fee    |  Undefined               |
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 5 |           Cautious Clay      |           Hip Hop & Rap, R&B             |   Call For Fee    |  Undefined               |
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 6 |           Andy Samberg       |           Standup Comedy                 |   Call For Fee    |  18-25,25-35,35-50       | 
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 7 |           Afrojack           |              DJ's                        |  Under $200,000   |  Under 18,18-25,25-35    |                    
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
 8 |           Billy Idol         |              Classic Rock                |  Under $200,000   |  25-35,35-50,50 +        |
---+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

```
artist.isnull().sum()
```

**pandas.get_dummies**
I read here and tried a few different things to no luck.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

**What i tried**

```
artist1["genre"] = artist1["genre"].astype(float)


artist1_features = pd.concat([artist1['genre'].str.get_dummies(sep="| "),
                              pd.concat([artist1['demo'].str.get_dummies(sep=","),
                              pd.get_dummies(artist1[['price']]),axis=1)
artist1["name"] = artist1["name"].map(lambda name:re.sub(''[^A-Za0-9]+', " ", name))                              
artist1_features.head()
```

**I also tried this**

```
artist1["genre"] = artist1["genre"].astype(float)
artist1_processed = pd.get_dummies(metadata['genre']).str.get_dummies(sep="| ")
artist1_concat = pd.concat([artist1_processed, metadata], axis=1)
pd.get_dummies(artists1[["genre"]]).head()
```

**errors I got**

[image]

**goal**

Ideally I would like to use **pd.get_dummies**, a pandas method for converting categorical features to data frames with dummy/indicator variables for each genres, demographics, and prices separately.

**Genres** 
has a separator like this "| " basically - 
ex: Country Music| Hip Hop & Rap| Pop Music

**demographics** 
has a separator like this "| " basically - 
ex: Under 18,18-25,25-35

**prices** 
does not need a separator but has a comma - 
ex:  Under $200,000

I am applying ideas from a few different movie database recommender systems tutorials into a real project.

which should look like the following once done.

**expected results**

**What I am trying to do:**

**Genre:**

```
id |            name              | Adult Contemporary | Classic Rock | Country Music | DJ's | Standup Comedy | Pop Music | Rock Music | Hip Hop & Rap | R&B |
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 1 |           Ace Frehley         |           0        |        1     |       0       |  0   |       0        |        0  |      1     |         0     |  0  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 2 |           Air Supply         |           1        |        0     |       0       |  0   |       0        |        1  |      0     |         0     |  0  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 3 |           Bebe Rexha         |           0        |        0     |       1       |  0   |       0        |        1  |      0     |         1     |  0  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 4 |           Blanco Brown       |           1        |        0     |       1       |  0   |       0        |        0  |      0     |         1     |  0  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 5 |           Cautious Clay      |           0        |        0     |       0       |  0   |       0        |        0  |      0     |         1     |  1  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 6 |           Andy Samberg       |           0        |        0     |       1       |  0   |       1        |        0  |      0     |         1     |  0  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 7 |           Afrojack           |           0        |        0     |       0       |  1   |       0        |        0  |      0     |         0     |  0  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
 8 |           Billy Idol         |           0        |        1     |       0       |  0   |       0        |        0  |      0     |         0     |  0  | 
---+------------------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+------+----------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----+
```

**Demographics:**

```
id |            name              | Under 18 | 18-25 | 25-35 | 35-50 | 50 + | Undefined |
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 1 |        Ace Frehley           |     0    |   0   |   1   |   1   |   1  |    0      |
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 2 |        Air Supply            |     0    |   0   |   0   |   1   |   1  |    0      |
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 3 |        Bebe Rexha            |     0    |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0  |    1      |    
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 4 |            Blanco Brown      |     0    |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0  |    1      | 
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 5 |            Cautious Clay     |     0    |   0   |   1   |   1   |   1  |    1      | 
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 6 |            Andy Samberg      |     0    |   1   |   1   |   1   |   0  |    0      | 
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 7 |            Afrojack          |     1    |   1   |   1   |   0   |   0  |    0      |  
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
 8 |            Billy Idol        |     0    |   0   |   1   |   1   |   1  |    0      | 
---+------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
```

**Price:**

```
id |            name              | Call For Fee | Under $15,000 | Under $25,000 | Under $50,000 | Under $75,000 | Under $100,000 | Under $150,000 | Under $200,000 |
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 1 |        Ace Frehley           |       1      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        0       |        0       |        0       |
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 2 |        Air Supply            |       0      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        1       |        0       |        0       |
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 3 |        Bebe Rexha            |       1      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        0       |        0       |        0       |
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 4 |            Blanco Brown      |       1      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        0       |        0       |        0       | 
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 5 |            Cautious Clay     |       1      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        0       |        0       |        0       |
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 6 |            Andy Samberg      |       1      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        0       |        0       |        0       |
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 7 |            Afrojack          |       0      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        0       |        0       |        1       | 
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 8 |            Billy Idol        |       0      |       0       |       0       |       0       |       0       |        0       |        0       |        1       | 
---+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

After I am done I would like to run a scaling function returns a numpy array containing the features KNN model from scikit-learn to the data and calculate the nearest neighbors for each distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your output with

```
artist1_features = pd.concat([artist1['genre'].str.get_dummies(sep="| "), 
                              artist1['demo'].str.get_dummies(sep=","),
                              pd.crosstab(artist1.index, artist1['price']),axis = 1)
```

Comment: dummies = artist1['genre'].str.get_dummies(sep='|')

Comment: final = pd.concat([artist1, dummies], axis=1)